# NoMethodError: undefined method `alias_method'

Tags: ruby

I am using some metaprogramming (using ruby 2.3.1) so that i can call a method before calling the actual method i want to call - like a before_filter/before_action.

The pseudocode below explains what i am trying to achieve

```
module Api
  def call_this_method_everytime
    if A
      go ahead and call the actual method being called
    else
      stop here do not call he method it was supposed to call
    end
  end

  def when_i_call_this_method

  end

  def or_this_method

  end
end
```

With the help of a SO member i was able to theoretically understand what i want to do using metaprogramming - which i arrived at the code below.

```
 module Api
    def heartbeat
      ...
    end

    def interceptor(name)
      original_method = "original #{name}"
      alias_method original_method, name
      define_method(name) do |*args|
        heartbeat
        result = send original_method, *args
        puts "The method #{name} called!"
        result
      end
    end

end
```

Instead of calling the method i want - i call interceptor method with the name of the actual function i want to call as an argument. I would then first call `heartbeat` function and if the check is OK then i proceed with actually calling the actual function.

However having limited knowledge of metaprogramming i am getting this error

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'alias_method'`

Searching around did not help. Any help appreciated.

Comment: alias_method is an Active Support method, that's why you're getting undefined here probably.

Comment: let me see if i understand correctly- when `interceptor(my_method)` is called, you want to modify my_method to first call heartbeat before going on with its original functionality? and in your code, you're using alias_method to create a sort of "copy" of the original method which you can then call in the modified method, once you've called heartbeat?

Comment: I previously misunderstood the question, below is an updated version closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PedroNascimento `alias_method` is [not an ActiveSupport method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method).

Comment: @Jordan whoops, you're right. `alias_method_chain` is the one that is from Active Support. :)

Comment: @eiko yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way of doing the same thing:

```
def interceptor(name, *args)
  if 1 == 1
    send name, args
  end
end

interceptor(:puts, "oi")
```

Comment: i think petros wants interceptor to be called once, causing future calls of the method to be intercepted. this would require interceptor to be called every time.

Comment: @eiko actually i want to cal it each time as i am checking if the server i will be sending a request in is "live" first and then sending the request.

Comment: Pedro thank you for the solution simple and neat! (we have the same name btw in diff language heh) However, how can i make the *args argument optional as not all functions need arguments?

Comment: Just set an empty array: *args = []

Comment: @PedroNascimento hmm doesn't seem to like it `syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
    def interceptor(name, *args = [])`

Comment: My mistake, if *args is nil, it will show up as an empty array. Check in your console: `*nil`.